# How to determine which table to add index?

Tags: sql

there.

I have a stored procedure which is low efficiency.

It was caused by table A left join table B, so I decided to add index to a table but I had no idea for determining which table to add.

Table A, which contains main information of the search.

Table B, which contains additional information for the main case.

Thanks all.

```
select * from main_case main
inner join (
    select case_seq, min(todo_seq) as min_todo_seq
    from case_todo todo
) todo on todo.case_seq = main.case_seq
inner join case_todo todo2 on todo2.todo_seq = todo.min_todo_seq
left join exchange_rate e_rate on e_rate.money_code = main.money_code
```

Comment: could you please show DDL of the involved tables and the query

Comment: I've add the sql code something like that

Comment: Show us table and index definitions, and the execution/explain plan output.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, your query is invalid and expected to raise an exception. The derived table (i.e. the subquery) needs a GROUP BY.

Comment: I found it was stucked when I joined table exchange_rate, dbms postgresql

Comment: I omiited it, sorry

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn.

Comment: Sorry, I can show the DDL for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you are short in time to investigate various options, and implications of having unnecessary indexes, and you are not inclined to share the table structures and the SQL, the simplest advice is to create an index on the join keys (the columns used in the join condition, and on the columns used for filtering on the WHERE clause.

Many factors influence if an index will be useful in a specific scenario, but if you can experiment, go for it.

Comment: add both column of the join keys of table a and b?

Comment: Yes, both (if they are both in the join)

Comment: I've add the sample code on post.

Comment: Main_case.case_seq, and exchange_rate.money_code, casetodo.todo_seq. try these for impact. Preferably one at a time

Comment: okay, I'll try.

Comment: Have you tried?